# Changing the value of the variable might be tricky-Java

Tags: java

That's the code in the method that changes the original value:

```
public void setSalary(MarriedPerson spouse){
 if(getSex() != spouse.getSex()) { setSalary(getSalary() + spouse.getSalary()); 
 } 
}
```

So what I'm doing is changing the value of the variable salary of an object when the object has the opposite sex from the other one (I'm actually adding them as you see like they're a couple). Anyway what's happening is that the first objects salary is now the sum of the 2 salaries and after the method call the salary permanatelly changes. What I want to do is not change it for ever but for this call only, just so that i print it . Here's the code in the main method:

```
MarriedPerson mp1 = new MarriedPerson("Tront", "Betty", 31, 980.5f,Person.FEMALE, 3); 
MarriedPerson mp2 = new MarriedPerson("Tront", "Kirk", 31, 2080f,Person.MALE, 2); 
MarriedPerson mp3 = new MarriedPerson("Tront", "Sonia", 31, 600f,Person.FEMALE, 0); 
mp1.printinfo(); 
mp2.printinfo(); 
mp3.printinfo(); 
//sal = mp1.getSalary();
mp1.setSalary(mp2); 
mp1.printinfo(); 
//mp1.setSalary(sal);
mp1.setSalary(mp3); 
mp1.printinfo(); 
mp1.setSalary(mp2.getSalary()); 
mp1.printinfo();
```

So if I uncomment the commands the program works fine but what I do is create another value, the sal and save the salary of mp1 object there. And by calling the `setSalary` method it works. I want a more proper way though, that works every time.

Comment: That's out of scope of this question, but couples might be same-sex. I think you should reconsider your definition of "couple"

Comment: well, true. I 'll let the teacher know.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a setter in the first place when you do not want to change the value?

A proper solution depends on what your bigger picture is.

You could set the married person with anew `setMarriedPerson()` to express the marriage and provide a refeence to that instance. And then later on use something like `printCoupleInfo()` to output combined values.

If you really are just interested in combined salary then a new `coupleSalary` field might fit your needs. (Initialized on your `setCoupleSalary()` to the same as salary in case of combinating condition fails and the sum if it holds.

Or if this *just to print it* is your major concern, then provide a `printCoupleSalary()' method that gets another MarriedPerson and outputs accordingly.

Comment: except for the comments the code is given and I have to use it for the excerise (college). So I guess I have to use the setters @rpy

Comment: But then, what are you supposed to to with the exercise? Just looking would for sure not be it. SO, is the signature of the class "fixed" or also the implementatin of the methods? Or maybe you are supposed to introduce new fields?

Comment: The only way to print the sum and not change a field would be to print the sum right withing the method.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a setSalary() method here if you don't want to change the salary attribute of the object.

Directly you can print the value of salary to be the sum of the two salaries if the condition is satisfied within the printInfo() method itself.

```
public void printInfo(MarriedPerson mp){
//code to print all the values
.......
.......
//check if one is male and other female, then print their combined salary
if(getSex()!=mp.getSex())
        System.out.println("Salary="+getSalary()+mp.getSalary());


}
```

It will only print the sum of two salaries ,if condition holds true without updating the salary value of the object.